# Why would anyone say "I'm a motherf***** starboy" instead of "I'm a starboy"?

Tags: meaning

What extra meaning does adding motherfuck***** add? Why would anyone want to call themselves motherfucking? Example, from a song by The Weeknd:

> I'm a motherfucking starboy.

Comment: [Motherfucking](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/motherfucking) is an _intensifier_, which basically means it is used to make a statement sound strong or extreme. It does not usually literally mean having sex with one's mother.

Comment: It's just an intensifier, albeit a rude one, but what's rude among some is commonplace among others. A motherfucker doesn't actually fuck mothers, just as a son of a bitch isn't actually the offspring of a canine female.

Answer (score 3):

The use of "bad" language ("bad" varies with social group and context) serves as an intensifier. So, a "motherf****** starboy" means the the speaker is claiming to be a really prime example. Note that I'm pretty sure you got your asterisk count wrong.

Comment: Just assume one or more of the asterisks represents an apostrophe.

Comment: Thank you @WhatRoughBeast. But what do you mean by a really prime example? Thanks.  I don't understand how they must be meeting their mothers after that.

Comment: @user72227 - See http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/prime%20example  third definition  Also, as Werrf answered, "motherfucking" has nothing to do with actually having relations with one's mother. It has become a generalized bit of bad language. Just as "badass" doesn't mean you have an anal disease.

Answer (score 2):

"Motherfucking" rarely actually references a person's literal mother, any more than "badass" references someone's digestion. Rather, a motherfucker is a person who defies social convention and norms - originally as a generic insult, then as a reference to something being tough or difficult, which then morphed into a description one might give themselves to show how unconventional and tough they were.

[Here's a short Slate article](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2013/02/14/_motherfucker_etymology_and_origins_how_it_became_badass_to_be_a_mofo.html) discussing the progress of 'motherfucker' from insult to badge of honour.

So in the line **I'm a motherfucking starboy**, "Motherfucking" serves as an intensifier indicating that one is not just a starboy, which could have rather effeminate implications, but one is a tough, strong, unconventional person who is also a Starboy.

Comment: I must say, I never expected to see such a scholarly answer, including a citation, about "motherfucker".